# runFeatureFile Error - BDD Katalon Studio

Tags: groovy, cucumber, katalon-studio

When I am using the cucumber **runFeatureFile** option, I am receiving the below error while running.

Please suggest to proceed further.

**LOG:**

```
2019-08-05 17:30:20.128 DEBUG testcase.GMPInquiry01 - 1: runFeatureFile(InquiryEARunnerOne)
2019-08-05 17:30:20.254 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor - :x: Test Cases/GMPInquiry01 FAILED.
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords.runFeatureFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class InquiryEARunnerOne]
Possible solutions: runFeatureFile(java.lang.String), runFeatureFile(java.lang.String, com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling), runFeatureFolder(java.lang.String), runFeatureFolder(java.lang.String, com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling)
at GMPInquiry01.run(GMPInquiry01:19)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:336)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:327)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:306)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:298)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:232)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:129)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:112)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:81)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
at TempTestSuite1565006403521.run(TempTestSuite1565006403521.groovy:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this keyword instead of `runFeatureFile()`:

```
CucumberKW.runWithCucumberRunner(InquiryEARunnerOne.class)
```

NOTE: this is from [this post](https://forum.katalon.com/t/runfeaturefile-error-bdd-katalon-studio/30875/3) in Katalon Forum.